# Use multiple models in as single controller MEAN.IO

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean.io

I am a newby when it comes to the mean stack. I generated a package ModelA. I also generated ModelB. I am now try to reference 2 models in ModelA controller. for example

Model/ModelA.js

```
var ModelA = new Schema({  
    name: String  
});

mongoose.model('ModelA', ModelA);
```

Model/ModelB.js

```
var ModelB = new Schema({  
   name: String  
});

mongoose.model('ModelB', ModelB);
```

package/contoller/ModelA.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
ModelA = mongoose.model('ModelA'),
ModelB = mongoose.model('ModelB'),
_ = require('lodash');
```

I keep getting MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model 'ModelB'. I guess my question is how do I reference modelB in controller/ModelA?

Comment: You don't seem to be `require`-ing the `Model/ModelA.js` and `Model/ModelB.js` files. Are you doing that elsewhere?

Comment: I haven't seen require used for models in mean.io. I have just using node and express. This controller works if I just comment out Line 3.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like the following:

Model/ModelA.js

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('ModelA', ModelA);
```

Then in any other file:

```
var ModelA = require('./path/to/Model/ModelA.js');
ModelA.find({}); // etc.
```

The `module.exports` will return you its value when it is `require`d in another file. Then when you need the instance/object you can assign the `require` to a `var` and act on it. In this case, `ModelA` is a Mongoose Model object that can be used wherever it gets included.